# Batch processing in Scala

Tags: scala, batch-file

I have a number of runnable programs written in Java that I'd like to set into one class that would run those one after another in Scala.  So for example I have classes:
RunMe with arguments "A", "B", "C"
WorkbookLoader with arguments "c:\workbooks\", "c:\sourceFile.bin" and "c:\targetFile.bin"

i just need those to call one after another.

Greatly appreciate for giving me an answer in advance.

Sincerely,

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Java's `Runtime#exec` method, just like in Java.  See the javadoc [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).